# Why when creating new GameObjects it's not changing the tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the first script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InstantiateObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;

    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;


    void Start()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        //generateObjectOnTerrain();
    }

    public void generateObjectOnTerrain(bool parent, string tag)
    {
        //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
        float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
        float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
        float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

        //Apply Offset if needed
        yVal = yVal + yOffset;

        //Generate the Prefab on the generated position        
        GameObject objInstance = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
        if (parent)
            objInstance.transform.parent = this.transform;
        objInstance.transform.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

And in the script that i'm using this:

```
private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cloneTeleportations; i++)
        {
            InstantiateObjects gos = GetComponent<InstantiateObjects>();
            gos.prefab = prefab;
            gos.generateObjectOnTerrain(true, "ddd");//"Teleportation");
        }
    }
```

If i will change it from true to false it will not make the GameObjects childs and if it's true they will be childs. The parent part is working.
But for testing i tried to change the tag to "ddd" and i saw in the first script that the tag is "ddd":

```
objInstance.transform.tag = tag;
```

tag is "ddd" and objInstance.transform.tag by default is "Teleportation" when running the game all the cloned gameobjects tagged as "Teleportation" and not "ddd".

Comment: Did you create a tag `ddd` in Unity?

Comment: Ahh right forgot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Unity` you must first add a `tag` manually from the Editor and only then you will be able to assign it to a `GameObject`. If the `tag` does not exist it's not possible to assign it.

Comment: @Programmer `SerializedProperty tagsProp = tagManager.FindProperty("tags");  string s = "the_tag_i_want_to_add";` It is possible to add a tag via `c#` script. I don't understand why you eddited my question please explain. :)

Comment: You **can't** add/create tag from script. You can only **change** tag from script.

Comment: I don't agree, could you please refer to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/33597/is-it-possible-to-create-a-tag-programmatically.html) article and confirm that it is obsolete. Thanks.

Comment: This is Editor script. You can almost do **anything** in the Editor with reflection or with Unity's Editor API. OP is not working on an Editor Script. This will fail when he build the game.

Comment: @Programmer corrected my answer :)

Comment: You also have to mention that this will only work in the Editor. I just don't want people to get the idea that one can create tags during-runtime.

Comment: I agree, It is possible tough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144347/discussion-between-hristo-and-programmer).